# Facebook Error: (#100) The specified scheduled publish time is invalid

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, axios

I'm building a platform to create and organise Social Media posts and publish them to Facebook via Facebook Graph API. I have set up the logic to get the required access tokens and immediately publishing posts to a Facebook page works perfectly fine. However, if I try to schedule the posts I always get the error

"**(#100) The specified scheduled publish time is invalid**".

I use a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed` to query Facebook Graph API with the following params

```
access_token=...
message=Test
published=false
scheduled_publish_time=time
```

where I calculate the UNIX timestamp by

```
const minutes = 15;
const time = new Date().getTime() + minutes * 60 * 1000;
```

Given the fact that I schedule the post 15 minutes in the feature, I assume that I have taken all necessary requirements into account (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/common-scenarios#scheduledposts).

**Edit**

As pointed out by @04FS you need to give the timestamp in seconds NOT milliseconds. Hence the following solved my problem

```
const minutes = 15;
const time = Math.round((new Date().getTime() + minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const minutes = 15;
const time = new Date().getTime() + minutes * 60 * 1000;
```

JavaScript’s `Date` object works in milliseconds, not seconds. Your JS code currently gives a value of around 1558015867708, and that would be the unix timestamp of 07/23/51341 @ 1:28am (UTC)

The API wants a proper unix timestamp in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Considering the same scenario in python datetime.strftime(time_object, %s) gives the required Unix timestamp in seconds but the API still throws the same error